# Memgraph shortest path between two nodes without weights or using *WSHORTEST

Tags: memgraphdb, opencypher

How do you return the shortest path between two nodes in Memgraph. I found the algorithm for the weighted shortest path in their documentation `[*WSHORTEST (r, n | r.weight)]`, but this is not what I am looking for. I need to find the shortest path between two specific nodes without using weights.

Neo4j has a way of doing this with Cypher's `shortestPath((startNode) - [*] - (endNode)` function, but as far as I know this is not supported in Memgraph which uses openCypher.

So the question is how to compute the shortest path in Memgraph; is there an algorithm for it or can I somehow use `WSHORTEST` without weights (I tried but could not made it work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cybersam is right! The variable length `bfs` is most likely what you want.

`wshortest` can also be used by specifying `1` in the expression part, so:

```
MATCH path=(n {id: 0})-[R:Edge *WSHORTEST (r, n | 1) total_weight]-(m {id: 9})
RETURN nodes(path), total_weight;
```

but it's too heavy for the simplest shortest path because it runs the full Dijkstra algorithm, which is not required if the weights are constants.

Comment: Thanks! I also managed to find the shortest path using `wshortest` after thinkering for a while more (as far as I tested it works with any positive number).
I have an additional question regarding `shortestpath` that neo4j uses and `wshortest` for memgraph. Is it true that these two are the closest when regarding which algorithm is used (if I am not mistaken they both use Dijkstra's algortihm to find the shortest path).

Comment: Looking at the [open source code for Memgraph](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/tree/d71b6a50071862df1aeae6b0dc62d70631c04ca4), `wshortest` requires extra overhead for handling weights as compared to `BFS`. During planning, it has to collect lambda function(s) to process the weight(s), and then when executing the plan it has to call the weight lambda(s). The `BFS` option has no weight overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Memgraph's [Breadth-first search](https://memgraph.com/docs/advanced-algorithms/built-in-graph-algorithms#breadth-first-search) is probably the most similar to `shortestpath`.

Here is an example from their documentation:

> The following query will show the `shortest` path between nodes `n` and `m`
> as a graph result.
>
> ```
> MATCH path=(n {id: 0})-[*BFS]->(m {id: 8})
> RETURN path;
> ```